# SQL table : update column with batchName based on the total count of rows

Tags: sql, cursor, slice, sql-server-2014, row-number

We have a SQL table with few columns and one of the columns is Item. It has various values shown below.

| Item |
| --- |
| Item1 |
| Item2 |
| Item3 |
| Item4 |
| Item5 |
| Item6 |
| Item7 |
| Item8 |
| Item9 |
| Item10 |
| Item11 |
| Item12 |

I need to divide this table into various sets based on the total number of rows in the table.
The maximum sets allowed vary, but for example, here I use it as 6.

So, if there  12 rows in the table, I need to assign batch1 to the first 2 rows, batch2 to 3rd/4th row, and so on. if there are 14 rows, it is fine for the last 4 rows to have batch6 (because 14 / 6=approx 2 rows per batch)

What I tried so far is to use row_number over Item such that I get a unique list of rows (Item will be unique in this table and in this example it will be 1 to 12). Then write cursor-based logic to loop through the count and based on the factor of 6, set the value for BatchName.

Desired output is

| Item | BatchName |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | Batch1 |
| Item2 | Batch1 |
| Item3 | Batch2 |
| Item4 | Batch2 |
| Item5 | Batch3 |
| Item6 | Batch3 |
| Item7 | Batch4 |
| Item8 | Batch4 |
| Item9 | Batch5 |
| Item10 | Batch5 |
| Item11 | Batch6 |
| Item12 | Batch6 |

What are the best options here? Any suggestions to produce this type of output?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use arithmetic.  In SQL Server, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       ( (row_number() over (order by item) + 1) / 2 ) as batch_number
from t
```